# How to setup a basic repository_rule?

Tags: bazel

I'm pretty lost trying to create a custom repository rule...

`pypi.bzl`:

```
def _impl(repository_ctx):                                                                           
  repository_ctx.execute(['echo', '"testing testing 123"'])                                                                                     
  repository_ctx.execute(['pip', 'download', repository_ctx.attr.package])                           
  repository_ctx.file("BUILD",                                                                                                                  
      """                                                                                            
  py_library(                                                                                        
    name = "lib",                                                                                    
    srcs = glob(["*.py"]),                                                                           
  )                                                                                                  
      """)                                                                                           

pypi_package = repository_rule(                                                                      
  implementation=_impl,                                                                              
  attrs={"package": attr.string(mandatory=True)},                                                    
)
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("//:pypi.bzl", "pypi_package")                                                                  

pypi_package(                                                                                        
  name = "dateutil",                                                                                                                            
  package = "python-dateutil",                                                                       
)
```

`BUILD`:

```
py_binary(                                                                                           
  name = "app",                                                                                                                                 
  srcs = ["app.py"],                                                                                 
  deps = ["@dateutil//lib"],                                                                                                                    
) 

$ bazel build app
ERROR: /Users/alec/code/bazel-pypi/BUILD:1:1: no such package '@dateutil//lib': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//:app'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:app' failed; build aborted.
```

I'm not sure how to even begin debugging the issue because it doesn't seem like the commands in my repository rule's implementation are even being run at all. (E.g., no output from `echo`). Obviously there won't be a `library` target if the `repository_ctx.file` call isn't happening...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says `no such package '@dateutil//lib'`, so a natural thing would be to use bazel query to determine what packages do exist:

```
$ bazel query @dateutil//...
ERROR: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ajmichael/473b6943104a48bd7642dd8ab62af629/external/dateutil/BUILD:2:2: indentation error.
ERROR: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ajmichael/473b6943104a48bd7642dd8ab62af629/external/dateutil/BUILD:5:3: Trailing comma is allowed only in parenthesized tuples.
ERROR: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ajmichael/473b6943104a48bd7642dd8ab62af629/external/dateutil/BUILD:6:6: syntax error at 'outdent': expected expression.
ERROR: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ajmichael/473b6943104a48bd7642dd8ab62af629/external/dateutil/BUILD:2:2: assignment length mismatch: left-hand side has length 2, but right-hand side evaluates to value of length 1.
ERROR: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ajmichael/473b6943104a48bd7642dd8ab62af629/external/dateutil/BUILD:6:6: contains syntax error(s).
ERROR: package contains errors: .
ERROR: error loading package '@dateutil//': Package '' contains errors.
```

So it looks like the BUILD file is malformed. particularly, you need to get rid of the indent before "py_library". Fixing that and trying again, we get

```
$ bazel query @dateutil//...
@dateutil//:lib
```

So the error is that your BUILD file contains "@dateutil//lib" instead of "@dateutil//:lib".

So now the question is, why is "@dateutil//:lib" correct? To understand that, you need to understand Bazel's label syntax. "@dateutil//lib" is a shorthand for "@dateutil//lib:lib", which means "the lib target in the lib package in the dateutil repository". The "lib package in the dateutil repository" corresponds to "lib/BUILD". But your repository rules writes "BUILD", not "lib/BUILD". So your target is created in the "" package. So the syntax for your py_library that you've created is "@dateutil//:lib".